# why mod (%) calculation result of zero will not consider as falsy in javascript condition evaluation

Tags: javascript

```
if (!5%5) {
  console.log('its a 5%!');
}

if (5%5 === 0) {
  console.log('its a 5%! but eval differently');
}
```

https://codepen.io/adamchenwei/pen/ZXNraK?editors=0010

Something like above you will only see 2nd statement to evaluate to be true. Why is that? Isn't first statement `!` help revert the value into true already. What did I missed?

Comment: Hint: Time to read up on [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Comment: feel so silly right now....

Comment: Happens to the best of us. If you ever get weirdness like this, hope you've learned to try applying `(...)` around parts to force a particular order of evaluation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `!5%5` is interpreted as if it were parenthesized `(!5)%5`. In other words, the `!` operator binds very tightly, so `!5` is evaluated *before* the `%` operator.

Consider an expression like `-x+y`.  Clearly, that means `(-x)+y`, and not `-(x+y)`, because of traditional arithmetic operator precedence rules. The `!` operator is in that respect similar to unary `-`.

The expression `!5` is `0`, and `0%5` is 0, so `!5%5` is not "truthy".

Answer (score 4):

`!5` is `0`.

`0 % 5` is falsy.

Therefore, your if doesn't trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the result of `5%5` is not a number (`NaN`), and you can't invert it. But if you will store this result into variable, or will wrap `5%5` into parentheses (which will change the order of execution) you can use it as you tried. Here are some rows, which should help you with understanding the behavior:

```js
var result = 5%5;

if (!result) {
  console.log('Works with variable');
}

if (!5%5) {
  console.log('Works without variable');
} else {
  console.log('!5%5 evaluates to "!NaN"');
}

if (!(5%5)) {
  console.log('!(5%5) works with parentheses');
} else {
  console.log('!(5%5) doesn\'t work');
}

console.log("The type of 5%5 is: ", typeof 5%5);
console.log("The type of (5%5) is: ", typeof (5%5));
console.log("The type of 5%5 stored in variable is: ", typeof result);
console.log("The type of !(5%5) is: ", typeof !(5%5));
```

Comment: `5%5` is definitely a number; specifically, `0`.

Comment: @Pointy, but why `console.log(typeof 5%5);` says that it's `NaN`?

Comment: Because `typeof 5%5` is interpreted as `(typeof 5) % 5`

Comment: Try `console.log(typeof (5%5))`

Comment: @Pointy, yes, sorry about stupid question, I've played around and found my mistake. I have updated the answer.